# Apache - Mod rewrite "or redirect"

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to make rewrite condition:

I want to redirect user to `/Cms/index.php/$1` when "cms" was found in URL for example: `http://example.com/cms/`

Otherwise I want to redirect to `/App/index.php/$1`, I've already made something but it gave me 500 Error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cms     /Cms/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$     /App/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks

**@edit**

I tried but it also made me 500.

**`error.log`**

```
[Sun Dec 23 19:40:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.vUse 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Every time you get a 500 error, there's something in the error log.  Go read it!

Comment: Have you enabled your `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: I note that you have no `()` capture group in the either rule, so `$1` is not populated. `RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)`,  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that apache doesn't run the rewrite-rules just once. It tries applying the rules until the url no longer changes (this makes mod_rewrite extremely powerful). That is why you get the error. The rules are creating a redirect loop.

e.g `/cms/test` directs to `/Cms/index.php/test`, which in turn is matches by the second rule, causing it to direct to `/App/index.php/Cms/index.php/test`, this url get matched again by the second rule, directing it to `/App/index.php/App/index.php/Cms/index.php/test` etc.

To prevent this loop, add a rewrite-condition:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cms     /Cms/index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Cms|App)
RewriteRule ^.*$     /App/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cms(.*)     /Cms/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     /App/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried but it also made me 500.

**`error.log`**

    [Sun Dec 23 19:40:54 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.vUse 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Dude, you have lots of nested redirects. I suppose you would be having a redirect for `/App/index.php/[something]` right? The total number of redirects allowed is only 10!

Comment: Hmm, I have only this 3x lines in .htaccess file. I also made my index.php with die() at the begginin and i got the same error

Comment: Dude, not here. In the `/Cms/` and `/App/` folders, any `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Hmm in /Cms/ or /App/ nope - but few are deeper like /App/Modules/.htaccess - deny from all, nothing else.

Comment: What do you want to do with the URLs here? I mean, what's the user providing URL and translated URL?

Comment: I have 2 directories in root, Cms and App, there is also .htacces.
I want to redirect user to /Cms/index.php/$1 when url is like http://example.com/cms/ Otherwise I want to redirect to /App/index.php/$1. So: http://example.com/homepage -> Redirecting to App, http://example.com/cms/homepage -> redirecting to Cms/index.php

Comment: When I changed second condition to: RewriteRule ^[^/]*$  /App/index.php/$1, it was better, /cms/ was working but /app/ not completely.